# Data not saved after reload using ngStorage

Tags: angularjs, ng-storage

I am creating a simple registration webapp which stores data in a local storage element. I am using ngStorage framework.
Here is my js code..

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage']);
var count = 1;
var id;

app.controller('myCtrl1', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope,$localStorage) {



    $scope.flag = false;

    $scope.goUrl = function (hash) { 
        $location.path(hash);
    };

    if ($localStorage.array==undefined)
    {
            $localStorage.array = [];
        }

    $scope.submit = function () {
        if($scope.flag == true)
        {
            $scope.edit();
            console.log(id);
        }
        else
        {
            $scope._add();
        }


    };




    $scope._add = function(){
        $scope.donor.id = count;
        ++count;
       $localStorage.array.push($scope.donor);
        $scope.donor = {}; 
        alert("Submitted");
    };

    $scope.array = $localStorage.array; //ctrl2

    $scope.delete = function (id) {
    --id; 
    if (id > -1) {
        $localStorage.array.splice(id, 1);
        }
    $scope.array = $localStorage.array;
    };

    $scope.open = function (x){
        $scope.flag = true;
        id = x;        


    };


    $scope.edit = function (){

        $scope.donor.id = id; 
        $localStorage.array[--id] = $scope.donor;
        $scope.array = $localStorage.array;



        $scope.donor = {};
        $scope.flag = false;

    };






}]);
```

When I reload the page or close the page, the data in localstorage is lost.
I checked in devtools. I can see that nothing is written into localstorage even though the app works fine for the current session. 
Is there something i am doing wrong? Let me know if you need more info..

Comment: What is your actual question? Please clarify.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check if the info is enough.